Вопрос по echarts совместно с angular
Всем привет! вопрос такой: у меня есть две функции, при выборе там уходит запрос на данные и установка у настроек графика this.chartOptions$ или же this.myCharts? на настройки по умолчанию, аналогично делаю и для uncheck, я кидаю свои настройки в поток, потом еще пытаюсь очистить и перезаписать, но настройки не применяются, в чем мб проблема?
//Обработка события выбора элемента в дереве(объекты), если выбран, то запрос на ноды внизу
    onNodeSelectObj(event) {
        if (!this.selectedNodesForBack) {
            this.selectedNodesForBack = [];
        }
        this.recursionNode(event.node);
        if (this.selectedNodesForBack.length > 0) {
            this.phase4Facade.selectedObj$.next(this.selectedNodesForBack);
        }
        this.selectedNodes = []
        this.phase4Facade.selectedNodesDebit$.next(this.selectedNodes);
        this.phase4Facade.selectedNodesObj$.next(this.selectedNodesObj);
        this.chartOptions$.next(this.defaultSettings);
        /* this.myCharts?.clear(); */
        this.myCharts?.setOption(this.defaultSettings, true);
    }

    onNodeUnselectObj(event) {
        const defaultSettings = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.defaultSettings)) || {};
        // Найти индекс элемента, который нужно удалить
        const index = this.selectedNodesForBack.indexOf(event.node.id);
        // Если элемент найден, удалить его из массива
        if (index > -1) {
            this.selectedNodesForBack.splice(index, 1);
        }
        // Проверить, есть ли данные для передачи в selectedObj$
        if (this.selectedNodesForBack?.length > 0) {
            // Если да, передаем их в selectedObj$
            this.phase4Facade.selectedObj$.next(this.selectedNodesForBack);
        } else {
            this.phase4Facade.selectedNodesObj$.next([])
            this.phase4Facade.treeNodesDebit$.next(null);
        }
        this.selectedNodes = []
        this.phase4Facade.selectedNodesDebit$.next(this.selectedNodes);
        this.phase4Facade.selectedNodesObj$.next(this.selectedNodesObj);
        console.log('this.chartOptions$1', this.chartOptions$.getValue());
        this.chartOptions$.next(defaultSettings);
        this.myCharts?.clear();
        this.myCharts?.setOption(defaultSettings, true);
        console.log('this.chartOptions$2', this.chartOptions$.getValue());
    }


как задать хороший вопрос
